# How to automate Android project skeleton creation? (no Android Studio)

Tags: android, templates, gradle, project-management

I would like to create a regular Android project skeleton (e.g. create directories for all the sources, resources, flavors dimensions, etc; create manifest and xml stubs)

I know you can do this in a shell script, but I want to use Gradle, if it is possible at all.

Is that functionality built into Gradle, or do I have to write my own extension/plugin. How does Studio create the project skeleton in actuality?

I don't want to re-invent the wheel, but I do not want the IDE.

Comment: "Is that functionality built into Gradle" -- no. "How does Studio create the project skeleton in actuality?" -- not by any means available to us from the command line, at least not in any documented form.

Comment: My question is concerned with *automation* of these tasks, not what they are.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is that functionality built into Gradle

There is no task presently in the Android Plugin for Gradle for creating an Android project. <strike>Google used to distribute the `android` tool that could create a project, but that was for the old Ant-based build process, and Google has never delivered a replacement.</strike> The old `android` tool, while still available, is deprecated and no longer has a sub-command for creating a project.

> How does Studio create the project skeleton in actuality?

It has its own template system that creates project files based upon the input that you provide via the new-project wizard. AFAIK this is just baked into the IDE; there is no documented CLI for accessing that functionality.

Comment: google still distributes the android tool... that's what you get in "tools-only" or "linux-dist"....

Comment: @Hatebit: Yes, but it is deprecated and does not fit the OP's requirements. I have updated the answer, though, as that was indeed a bug in the answer itself. Thanks for pointing this out!

Comment: @Hatebit: Sorry, your original comment came a few days after the question and my answer, and I missed the connection.

Comment: I don't mind, but I did change my id name at one point or the other. It's funny, those situations, we should compile these "bloopers" ha