# How to automate Android project skeleton creation without Android Studio? (2021)

Tags: android, android-studio, templates, project, deprecated

I KNOW THIS QUESTION IS VERY SIMILAR TO [THIS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54846173/how-to-automate-android-project-skeleton-creation-no-android-studio), with time difference.

I would like to create a regular Android project skeleton (create directories for all the sources, resources, flavors dimensions, etc; create manifest and xml stuff).

I have setup linux with latest *Android Command line tools only*, java, gradle, adb and a text editor; and I know how to build an app and test an app on a device.

I don't want to re-invent the wheel, but I do not want the IDE.

So far I found:

- [`android create project` is now deprecated](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20801042/how-to-create-android-project-with-gradle-from-command-line).
- You can use SDK versions previous to 25.0.3 to use `android create project`. (not a good solution)
- You can generate the project on AS and copy it, proceduraly. (not a good solution)

So...

**Is there any way to generate the mentioned project skeleton from command line with latest standards?**

*EDIT: It doesn't have to be an official google thing.*

Comment: There is no official solution from Google for this, if that is what you are asking. There might be a third-party project generator that is available, though I do not know of one.

Comment: thanks, I just clarified that on the question.